# Swift Collection View custom layout change cell width in cell side

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Hello i have working collectionview custom layout codes but some cells i need to change cell width in cell side comming varible from json dynamicly.

My CustomCollectionViewLayout

```
import UIKit

public var CELL_HEIGHT = 22.0
public var CELL_WIDTH = 40.0 // HERE WIDTH SOME CELLS MUST BE 80

class CustomCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    // Used for calculating each cells CGRect on screen.
    // CGRect will define the Origin and Size of the cell.

    let STATUS_BAR = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.height

    // Dictionary to hold the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes for
    // each cell. The layout attribtues will define the cell's size 
    // and position (x, y, and z index). I have found this process
    // to be one of the heavier parts of the layout. I recommend
    // holding onto this data after it has been calculated in either 
    // a dictionary or data store of some kind for a smooth performance.
    var cellAttrsDictionary = Dictionary<NSIndexPath, UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes>()

    // Defines the size of the area the user can move around in
    // within the collection view.
    var contentSize = CGSize.zero

    // Used to determine if a data source update has occured.
    // Note: The data source would be responsible for updating
    // this value if an update was performed.
    var dataSourceDidUpdate = true

    override func collectionViewContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return self.contentSize
    }

    override func prepareLayout() {

        // Only update header cells.
        if !dataSourceDidUpdate {

            // Determine current content offsets.
            let xOffset = collectionView!.contentOffset.x
            let yOffset = collectionView!.contentOffset.y

            if collectionView?.numberOfSections() > 0 {
                for section in 0...collectionView!.numberOfSections()-1 {

                    // Confirm the section has items.
                    if collectionView?.numberOfItemsInSection(section) > 0 {

                        // Update all items in the first row.
                        if section == 0 {
                            for item in 0...collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section)-1 {

                                // Build indexPath to get attributes from dictionary.
                                let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: section)

                                // Update y-position to follow user.
                                if let attrs = cellAttrsDictionary[indexPath] {
                                    var frame = attrs.frame

                                    // Also update x-position for corner cell.
                                    if item == 0 {
                                        frame.origin.x = xOffset
                                    }

                                    frame.origin.y = yOffset
                                    attrs.frame = frame
                                }

                            }

                            // For all other sections, we only need to update
                            // the x-position for the fist item.
                        } else {

                            // Build indexPath to get attributes from dictionary.
                            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: section)

                            // Update y-position to follow user.
                            if let attrs = cellAttrsDictionary[indexPath] {
                                var frame = attrs.frame
                                frame.origin.x = xOffset
                                attrs.frame = frame
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }


            // Do not run attribute generation code
            // unless data source has been updated.
            return
        }

        // Acknowledge data source change, and disable for next time.
        dataSourceDidUpdate = false

        var maxItemInASection: Int?

        // Cycle through each section of the data source.
        if collectionView?.numberOfSections() > 0 {
            for section in 0...collectionView!.numberOfSections()-1 {

                // Cycle through each item in the section.
                if collectionView?.numberOfItemsInSection(section) > 0 {
                    for item in 0...collectionView!.numberOfItemsInSection(section)-1 {

                        // Build the UICollectionVieLayoutAttributes for the cell.
                        let cellIndex = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: section)
                        let xPos = Double(item) * CELL_WIDTH
                        let yPos = Double(section) * CELL_HEIGHT

                        let cellAttributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWithIndexPath: cellIndex)
                        cellAttributes.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: yPos, width: CELL_WIDTH, height: CELL_HEIGHT)

                        // Determine zIndex based on cell type.
                        if section == 0 && item == 0 {
                            cellAttributes.zIndex = 4
                        } else if section == 0 {
                            cellAttributes.zIndex = 3
                        } else if item == 0 {
                            cellAttributes.zIndex = 2
                        } else {
                            cellAttributes.zIndex = 1
                        }

                        // Save the attributes.
                        cellAttrsDictionary[cellIndex] = cellAttributes

                        if maxItemInASection < item {
                            maxItemInASection = item
                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }

        // Update content size.
        let contentWidth = Double(maxItemInASection ?? 0) * CELL_WIDTH
        let contentHeight = Double(collectionView!.numberOfSections()) * CELL_HEIGHT
        self.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)

    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

        // Create an array to hold all elements found in our current view.
        var attributesInRect = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

        // Check each element to see if it should be returned.
        for cellAttributes in cellAttrsDictionary.values.elements {
            if CGRectIntersectsRect(rect, cellAttributes.frame) {
                attributesInRect.append(cellAttributes)
            }
        }

        // Return list of elements.
        return attributesInRect
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cellAttrsDictionary[indexPath]!
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange(newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

}
```

And here my cell codes.

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("customCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

     if items[indexPath.section].base == 2 {

              cell.label.text = items[indexPath.section].base


             cell.frame.size.width = 80
             cell.layer.frame.size.width = 80

             CELL_WIDTH = 80.0 // HERE I CHANGED SOME CELLS WIDTH 80 BUT DONT CHANGE THEM !!

}else{

   cell.label.text = items[indexPath.section].base



}
```

You can see top side

> CELL_WIDTH = 80.0 // HERE I CHANGED SOME CELLS WIDTH 80 BUT DONT CHANGE THEM !!

Comment: any idea ? i working but i didnt resolve this issue about 2 days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeForItemAtIndexPath` is not present for `UICollectionViewLayout`. So your `CustomCollectionViewLayout` inherited from `UICollectionViewLayout` does not have a protocol. You can create a `protocol` `widthForItemAtIndexPath` method.

```
protocol CustomCollectionViewDelegateLayout: NSObjectProtocol {
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, widthForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
}
```

In your `viewController` implemented this protocol method. Return value will be the width for the given `indexPath`

```
extension CustomCollectionViewController: CustomCollectionViewDelegateLayout {

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, widthForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        //from indexPath.section and indexPath.item identify double width item
        if sirano == 2 && satimdurum == 0 {
            return regularWidth * 2
        }
        return regularWidth
    }
}
```

In `prepareLayout()` method of your `CustomCollectionViewLayout` you can calculate position of each item you need to check which item should be double.

```
guard let width = delegate?.collectionView(collectionView!, layout: self, widthForItemAtIndexPath: cellIndex) else {
                        print("Please conform to CustomCollectionViewDelegateLayout protocol")
                        return
                    }
```

Made a demo project with Xcode 7.2 here at https://github.com/rishi420/UICollectionviewsample

Answer (score 3):

You could implement `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` instead of subclassing UICollectionViewLayout - unless you have other reasons to do that.

It would go somewhat like:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

    if indexPath.item % 3 == 0 { // <-- your condition here
        return CGSize(width: 40, height: 22) 
    }
    return CGSize(width: 80, height: 22)

}
```

By the way, don't forget to set your collectionView's delegate in order for this method to be called.

***UPDATED***

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if items[indexPath.section].base == 2 {
        return CGSize(width: 80, height: 22)
    } else {
        return CGSize(width: 44, height: 22)
    }
}
```

This is how I think your method should look like.
At your `cellForItem` you only need to worry about setting the labels, let the above code take care of the size of the cells.

Comment: Thanks for answer but i added your code inside my viewcontroller but dont works ,  also items[indexPath.section].base line comming from json when json value = 2 will be do width * 2 that cell.label width

Comment: i need to use width * 2 codes inside -- >   func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {   }  i think with if json value ...

Comment: What I was suggesting is for you to use the `collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` method **instead** of implementing the UICollectionViewLayout subclass. Just adding the code as it is in the answer won't work. You would have to substitute your condition and appropriate size inside the method.

Comment: I updated the answer with what I think your code would look like. Tell me if it works =D

Answer (score 1):

Do not change cell size inside the cellForItemAtIndexPath method. The cell layout is already set after dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier.

Change it in the sizeForItemAtIndexPath. This is called before the above delegate method.